# How to filter onDetached out of onCreated chrome listener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension where I want to perform a task when a window is created, but not when a window is created by detaching an existing tab.

So far what I've got is

```
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function(window) {

    if (window.WindowType !== 'normal') return;

   // rest of function...
```

I'm already filtering out popups with the second line, but I can't figure out how to filter out detaching tabs, even after scouring the `chrome.tabs` API.

I know there is a `chrome.tabs.OnDetached.addListener` function, but I don't see how to use it to *not* do what's written in the `onCreated` listener I already have.

Comment: There may be solutions or workarounds depending on what you need to do afterwards and whether this decision has to be made synchronously i.e. inside the currently executed event loop task.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I basically just want to open a new tab to a specific URL, using `chrome.tabs.create()` when a new _normal_ window is created, unless it was created by detaching an existing tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When a new window is opened **two** `onCreated` events are fired: for the window & tab.
- When a tab is detached **one** `onCreated` event is fired for the window.

Based on this it's possible to use two listeners to filter out the detaching:

```
let newWindowId;

chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(w => {
  newWindowId = w.id;
});

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
  if (newWindowId === tab.windowId) {
    chrome.windows.get(newWindowId, {populate: true}, w => {
      if (w.tabs.length === 1) {
        chrome.tabs.create({
          url: 'https://www.example.org',
          active: false,
          windowId: newWindowId,
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```